# data not adding in custom wordpress table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one shortcode for the form for filling date. shortcode is working properly as per the requirement but the date is not submitting into the data table.

I don't know what is actual problem accruing for filling data.

here is my user shortcode for the adding date

```
function userdash1()
{?>
  <div class="my">
  <form method="POST" action="">
<input type="date" name="edate" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form></div>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

    global $wpdb;
     $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);
}

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $date=$_POST['edate'];
      $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'exam';
      $wpdb->insert(
        wp_pte_exam,
        array(
          'id' => 1,
          'uid' => $uid,
          'e_date' => $date
        ) );
      echo '<script>alert("Question added");</script>';
     $wpdb->last_error('not given');
exit;
}
}
add_shortcode('users', 'userdash');
```

Comment: Maybe start by actually including any potential error messages in the output you are returning? `$wpdb->last_error();` would just _return_ any just error message at this point - but it doesn’t make its way into the output, unless you actually echo or print it …

Comment: not given any messages in output

Comment: Well then do some debugging earlier in the process, like verify whether it goes into your if branch there in the first place.

Comment: Btw., why are you embedding jQuery inside your `$tableData` there? WP already comes with jQuery embedded in almost all cases, so likely you’d be including it a second time here, or in a different version (but without using noconflict mode) - that is asking for trouble.